# Shell Script to Delete Files with Spaces

Tags: linux, bash, shell, command, sh

I'm trying to delete **all** files in a certain folder with an .sh script (linux) which are older than one day. This script is running daily and needs to delete all files in the "DTV" folder. So far I have tested with a .sh file called (full file path shown):

```
/volume1/tasks/dtv_delete_old_files.sh
```

This file contains the following command inside:

```
find /volume1/video/DTV/ -mtime +1 -exec rm {} \;
```

The folder location where the files inside need to be deleted are located here:

```
/volume1/video/DTV
```

The files inside this folder have the following naming format (full path shown):

```
/volume1/video/DTV/2016-02-19_1859_BBC NEWS_BBC News.ts
```

The script is unsuccessful deleting the files. I believe this is due to the fact that the file has spaces in the filename. Does anyone know how I could formulate the script so that all files in the DTV folder would be deleted (excluding the folder itself). Any feedback would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's `man find`:

> When find figures out how many 24-hour periods ago the file was last accessed, any fractional part is ignored, so to match -atime +1, a file has to have been accessed at least *two* days ago.

Use `-mtime +0` to delete files that are 24+ hours old. Spaces don't matter.

Comment: You are genius!! It worked... the problem was that the files were not old enough and your suggestion for +0 solved my problem ... thanks.